# Devise User's password gets overwritten upon updating any other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

**Problem**

When I use user.update(not_password_attribute: 'value') for the **first time in the session** the SQL query includes this:
*UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1,* so the encrypted password gets overwritten, and the **password** the user had before is **no longer valid** (checked with #valid_password? method).

However, when I update the same user for the second time within one session the *encrypted_password* is no longer added to the SQL query.

But when close the rails console and open it again the first scenario happens again.

Here is the output from the rails console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktTgJ.jpg

The same happens if I use user.update_without_password
[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0TUi.png)

I used the console to demo that the problem is not within controllers but it happens whenever the user is updated from any of the controllers including Active Admin or UsersController etc.

I tried using Devise 4.7.2 which I used in a previous project where this issue did not occur. But the outcome was the same.

**Question**

**How do I update the user without the password being overwritten?**

Some explanation why this happens would also help.

**I am using**

- Rails 6.0.3.4
- Devise 4.7.3
- Active Admin 2.9.0 b9076eb (don't think the issue is in Active Admin but trying to provide all the information here)

**Devise Config** (in */app/config/inintializers/devise.rb*)

```
config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12
config.reconfirmable = true
config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
config.password_length = 6..128
config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

*None of these seem relevant to the problem but, again, trying to provide as much information as possible*

**User model** (in */app/models/user.rb*)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

# some methods here but none overwrites Devise or ActiveRecord methods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I am completely sure what might be going there but I have a few guesses.

So, it seems like your issue is: `user.update(first_name: 'one')` is triggering a callback that attempts to update encrypted password even when an actual password is not provided or it is considered blank. But there is more.

**Why it doesn't get triggered for the subsequent update (`user.update(first_name: 'two')`**?

Possible explanation for that one is - perhaps callback is not triggered if logic behind it figures out that the password is now the same as the one we have set with the first command (ie blank) or the user object we call the second update on has encrypted password field populated after we executed the first update.

Ok, but then, **rerunning the console again, and for the same user that we previously set blank password for, we again get encrypted_password update?**

Looking at the encrypted password being set in the new console and observing that it is different than the previous one, we can reason that either blank case is handled by assigning random encrypted password, or there is a monkey-patch causing DeviseEncryptor (see https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/98fc5e8e396b66b826528811287ea6680a6d0757/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L71) to somehow generate different result based on current session (this would probably break a lot more things thus highly-unlikely).

The weirdest one is **update_without_password still adding encrypted password to query???**

Explanation - whatever was previously mentioned seems to affect update_without_password in a similar manner.

**The solution**

1. I think you can solve your issue if you use update methods that skip callbacks like: `update_column` or `update_columns` (see: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)
2. If you really want to understand what is going on exactly I would suggest to take a look at this file from devise source: `https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb`. Then, after you get a grasp of the code there, you can perhaps find the same source file in your local environment (wherever devise gem is installed), and instrument it with logs (`puts`) and check / patch it out yourself.

   *Note*: a few nice 'techniques' are described here:
   https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html
3. It would also be a good idea to disable spring while debugging weirdnesses like this. Good luck!

As a bonus - you can get some more context about why things around devise user update work the way they do by reading this discussion: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5033 I believe ActiveAdmin was also mentioned in the discussion. Tbh, I originally thought you had the same issue as them but the affected version does not match with the one you shared.